# "string indices must be integers" when trying to load test yaml data

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, unit-testing, yaml

I'm trying to figure out how to load test data in Django and Python 3.7.  I have the below YAML file

```
website:
 - id: 1
   path: "/test"
```

Pretty basic.  In my unit test, I attempt to load it using

```
management.call_command('loaddata', 'test_data.yaml', verbosity=0)
```

But this results in the below error.  What's wrong with my YAML file that would cause the below error?

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_add_articlestat (mainpage.tests.FirstTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/mainpage_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/pyyaml.py", line 73, in Deserializer
    yield from PythonDeserializer(yaml.load(stream, Loader=SafeLoader), **options)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/mainpage_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/python.py", line 91, in Deserializer
    Model = _get_model(d["model"])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: should it be `- path:` instead of `path:` in the yaml file?

Comment: Gave that a whirl but it resulted in the same error.

Comment: What is the app and model name? The correct format for the first line is `-model: appname:modelname`. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/initial-data/#providing-data-with-fixtures

Comment: Thanks @Selcuk, that was the issue.

Comment: Posting a proper answer to help future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

The first line does not look right to me:

```
website:
```

The correct format is

```
-model: appname:modelname
```

See [providing data with fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/#providing-data-with-fixtures) for details